# Memory mapped file truncation on windows

Tags: windows, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

Why can't we truncate memory mapped file on windows? Say I have mapped 4kb file and only used 2kb. So to truncate the 2kb, I need to first unmap the mapped file and then truncate it. why is this case? Is there a problem with API or my understanding is wrong?

Comment: Pretty fundamental, not how it is designed.  Creating a view that only maps a portion of the file content to memory is entirely normal, in fact a very common usage in the olden days.  It cannot possibly assume what the program decided to not map is junk that needs to be deleted.  Big bummer when the program crashes for example.  Growing the file is not a problem, the programmer's intention is unambiguous.

Comment: Have you looked in to using sparse files? It wont allow you to truncate files, but if you dont write to a area of a file, it wont take up space.

Comment: I tried memory-mappping file and I can see on-disk file size equivalent to the size I provided in the createFileMapping API. So even if I don't write anything in the file, I see the non-zero file size. And say to truncate that empty file in half, I have to first unmap the file.

Answer (score 0):

Because on Windows once file region is mapped, it cannot be removed.

What happens when you map 32kb file into memory, then truncate it to 0. What should happen once you access that mapping? On POSIX systems memory access will generate a signal which will probably crash your process. On Windows this is simply not allowed.

This behavior is supposed to make programming with memory-mapped files easier as handling error code is easier that signal handling.

Because of this, `CreateFileMapping` extends file size to the size of created mapping object.